# How do I enable "Technical Translation" in debug mode on Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo-10, debug-mode

I've got two servers running odoo 10. One has "Technical Translation" in the debug mode as the screenshot shows->

[image]

However on the other one, there are much less options in debug mode->
[image]

What could have led to this and how can I fix it (and including the other missing options)?

Comment: Check your access right. May be some of them is missing .

Comment: @KevalMehta Thanks for the response! By access right do you mean different modes? Such as user mode and developper mode? I thought only in developpers mode can one enter debug mode...if this is not the case, where should I check my access rights? Sorry, new to odoo...

Comment: By access rights means from res.users you can give access rights to particular logged in user. I am asking to check that rights.

Answer (score 0):

Give **Administrator -> Settings** access right to the user and try again.